# How to use Dynamic Radio button in aspx.cs file

Tags: c#, java, asp.net

I have created DYNAMIC radio button list from java script and now i want to use this radio button list in aspx.cs page, how can i do?

Comment: How are you creating this radio button list? Show your code? What do you want to use in the code behind more precisely?

Comment: When creating a control on client side you can't access it server side. Though you might be able to make a PageMethod and let a Javascript make an Ajax call to that?

Comment: Can you find it in `Request.Form` collection ?

Answer (score 0):

The server-side code will be unaware of a control dynamically created in JavaScript on the client-side. Likewise, the viewstate of the control will be invalidated if you create options in the list that aren't available at runtime.

In order to access the values in the code behind, you'll need to pass the values either with AJAX or set a hidden field value prior to postback.